# How to change the url route in the route.config file for the specific controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

i working in mvc4 with c# web application we have more controller and view in our web application we have configured route for all controller action method in route.config file as

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "User", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

it display the url like `http://localhost:21638/WebFileViewer/WebDocumentViewer?fileId=21` in all over the application, we have one controller that task is to display the file uploaded by the client in the web browser the file viewer page has url like the above one it displays the file id in the url, i want to hide the query string parameter for this controller only how will i change the route configure file to aspect my requirement?

Expected resultant url: `http://localhost:21638/WebFileViewer/WebDocumentViewer`

Comment: What does this have to do with jQuery? Also you can't hide the parameters of a GET. You could instead change your code to use POST request.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `TempData` for this:

```
TempData["FileId"] = "bla";

//this will make sure the data is kept when the user refreshes the page    
TempData.Keep();
RedirectToAction("WebDocumentViewer", "WebFileViewer");
```

then in `WebDocumentViewer` retrieve the value of `TempData["FileId"]`.

You won't have to make any changes to your `RouteConfig.cs` file.

Comment: And what about when the user refreshes the browser?